# Positioning views in Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to create a screen with coordinator layout that includes:

- Toolbar
- Fragment, which will be replaced for every page using navigation API
- Bottom App bar

However, I am struggling with positioning views in a way so the app's bottom bar doesn't overlap what in the fragment.

Any chance you could help me out with this, please? From what I can tell, the only way is to add a margin at the bottom but this may not be consistent across devices.

To illustrate, this list has a total of 25 items but the last two are overlapped by the app's bottom bar.

[image]

**activity main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/include">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:text="Test 1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:text="Test 2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:id="@+id/include"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="right|top"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bar"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content main xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
            android:layout_width="411dp"
            android:layout_height="627dp"
            android:name="com.example.fitnessfatality.startScreen.StartFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you use ConstraintLayout for that?

Comment: I thought of using constraint layout but bottom app bar with anchored FAB only works with constraint layout. I also want to learn how to implement scrolling behaviours once I find a solution for this issue.

Comment: Found anything? I have the same issue just single frame layout.

Comment: Use android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" or bottomPadding and cliptopadding="false" the padding value can be obtained from the navigationbar top

Answer (score 14):

Use these 3 properties to position each other

```
android:layout_gravity=""
app:layout_anchorGravity=""
app:layout_anchor="@id/xxxx"
```

Also here is an complete xml that can help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".home.HomeFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/app_barlayout"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collaps_toolabar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_currentMatch_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_barlayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

   

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: That solved my issue but is not suitable for the original post case as you cannot duplicate the properties you propose to align to both appbar and bottom navigation view.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LinearLayout inside CoordinatorLayout to arrange your views if it fits your needs or ConstraintLayout

---

I hope that the basis of the decision is clear. Take a look at this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
                layout="@layout/content_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bar"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is a viable solution but it does not utilise the bottom app bar and loses that nice effect you get with it :) I will probably hide the bottom bar on scroll to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Jeremi when does the bottom bar should be displayed? Only when you fully scroll the list down?

Comment: or is the bottom bar behaves like a snackbar?

Comment: I wanted to display the bottom bar all the time and only hide the tab layout on scroll.

Comment: I just managed to hide the bottom app bar when scrolling down and display it again when scrolling up :) It has a very pleasing effect and only needed to add bar.hideOnScroll = true I would say will be nice to add some extra bottom padding just in case if there aren't enough items in the list to scroll, as otherwise, some items may still remain invisible.